# Is there a simpler way to print a given variable without having to use the print function over and over?

Tags: python

I'm sure there is, I'm a beginner and struggling big time here! I know it can be done with simpler `print` statements but it doesn't seem to work with the following:

```
def calc_grade(n):
    if n < 40:
        return "E"
    elif n < 50:
        return "D"
    elif n < 60:
        return "C"
    elif n < 70:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "A"

n = 35
print("The grade letter for the mark 35 is " + calc_grade(n))

n = 4
print("The grade letter for the mark 44 is " + calc_grade(n))

n = 52
print("The grade letter for the mark 52 is " + calc_grade(n))

n = 65
print("The grade letter for the mark 65 is " + calc_grade(n))

n = 88
print("The grade letter for the mark 88 is " + calc_grade(n))
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what isn't working.

Comment: Use a loop?... Where are the values of `n` coming from?

Comment: you can move the print function inside the method, assign the value after evaluation to a variable and print it.

Comment: Well, there are 5 print statements there. I'd imagine there is a way to just use one print statement and change the value of "n" each time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is quite simple using a `for` loop:

```
list_of_values = [35, 44, 52, 65, 88]
for value in list_of_values:
    print("The grade letter for the mark {} is {}".format(value, calc_grade(value)))
```

Comment: Nice solution indeed, but perhaps using f strings would be even more "clean" -> https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine. What error message do you get?

Anyway: To simplify your code you can use a for loop:

```
points = [35, 44, 52, 65, 88]
for n in points: 
    print(f"The grade letter for the mark {n} is {calc_grade(n)}")
```

Comment: Hi I used the loop, as suggested, and now I am getting a Syntax error as follows:

Comment: File "question2.py", line 23
    print(f"The grade letter for the mark {n} is {calc_grade(n)}")
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax          The ^ is pointing to the last quotation mark

Comment: @L'Agatha Which python version do you use? Only Python 3.6+ supports f-strings.

Comment: Yes, I use python 3.8.5

Comment: Recheck your syntax. Copy paste my code. And watch after wrong indentations.

Comment: OK, i typed into terminal: python3 question2.py, rather than python question2.py and it worked. Ty

Answer (score 0):

You can print all your values with a single line of code:

```
vals = [35, 44, 52, 65, 88]
print(*(f'The grade letter for the mark {v} is {calc_grade(v)}' for v in vals), sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
The grade letter for the mark 35 is E
The grade letter for the mark 44 is D
The grade letter for the mark 52 is C
The grade letter for the mark 65 is B
The grade letter for the mark 88 is A
```

---

[EXTRA] Here is a possible solution to improve the `calc_grade` function:

```
import math

grades = [(40, 'E'), (50, 'D'), (60, 'C'), (70, 'B'), (math.inf, 'A')]
def calc_grade(n):
    return next(g for v, g in grades if n < v)
```

If you think `n` might have an infinite value, you can do something like this (credits to @Chris_rands):

```
grades = [(40, 'E'), (50, 'D'), (60, 'C'), (70, 'B')]
def calc_grade(n):
    return next((g for v, g in grades if n < v), 'A')
```

Comment: While an improvement on the working part, this is not an answer to the question whatsoever

Comment: What if they get an infinite grade? ;) seriously though i think i prefer to leave A out of the list and use `next((g for v, g in grades if n < v), "A")`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Well, that's probably not the case if we are talking about grades. I put in the list because the user might want to change the name of the grade without editing the function

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array with all of the possible values
Then walk through each value by a for-each loop

```
array = [35, 44, 52, 65, 88]
for n in array:
    print(f"The grade letter for the mark {n} is {calc_grade(n)}")
```

### Output

```
The grade letter for the mark 35 is E
The grade letter for the mark 44 is D
The grade letter for the mark 52 is C
The grade letter for the mark 65 is B
The grade letter for the mark 88 is A
```

---

Comment: Do you know why I am getting a syntax error?File "question2.py", line 23
    print(f"The grade letter for the mark {n} is {calc_grade(n)}")
                                                                ^

Comment: f-string is the newest Python syntax to do string formatting. It is available since Python 3.6. Python f-strings provide a faster, more readable.... Please check your python version

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for print

```
def calc_grade(n):
    if n < 40:
        return "E"
    elif n < 50:
        return "D"
    elif n < 60:
        return "C"
    elif n < 70:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "A"

def print_function(n):
    print("The grade letter for the mark " + str(n) + " is " + calc_grade(n))

print_function(35)
print_function(44)
print_function(52)
print_function(65)
```

Comment: This code has literally the same problem that OP wanted to solve (calling the print function multiple times). You just wrote a wrapper for the built-in print function.